# What's the difference between a regular CM and a Staff CM?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, community-managers

I noticed there was an opening for a Staff CM on the work here page.

Broadly speaking - the requirements are identical to our regular CMs.

[image]

Requirements seem the same, with the 3-5 year experience minimum

[image]

No mention of needing to own a staff or being given a staff

[image: Moria Mining Co is seeking staff to deal with a Balrog problem. Inquire within]

In case our CMs need to deal with Balrogs

The job scope too seems identical

So - what's the difference between our "regular" CMs and a staff CM?

Comment: Note how the benefits are restricted to those living in the United States. Though many feel that the US is behind the times with how it handles employment, no other country on earth can guarantee that its employees will not be poked with a sharp stick.

Comment: Well - there may be specific legal requirements elsewhere. As someone who periodically haunts the page, pretty sure almost all of that is boilerplate, and the sharp stick clause is a tradition worth keeping ;)

Comment: Now I wish I had a Staff to fight a balrog.

Comment: Not sure y'all have the vfx budget for a balrog . I think we could swing a troll though

Comment: Lucky that you took screenshots, link is now dead, they removed the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the novice [Greenhouse](https://www.greenhouse.io/) (the platform SE uses internally for hiring) user, I am to blame for this error. A Staff Community Manager is an IC with 12+ years of Online Community Management, in addition to several years of management experience either at the Manager or Director level. A Community Manager has between 3-5 years of experience managing an online community.

Key take away for me: Practice in the Sandbox, that's what it's for.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Just want to check - since there is no staff indicator, you're from the company and this is an official answer right?

Comment: Confirmed official answer.

Comment: I'll also say, these things happen, and meta, and *some of us* are more pendantic than most. Unless you took down the platform, but I once took out helpdesk for my workplace shortly before I was sent home sick... and the problems started later :D

Answer (score 14):

This opening being published was a mistake - we're not currently hiring for a Staff Community Manager - nor plan to advertise a job for it directly.

Last year and this year, we've been working on defining and creating horizontal progression inside the company for folks across several roles, and Community Management is one of them.

The Staff Title is both an indication of seniority as well as skill level and knowledge depth of the profession (and some other indicators relating to job performance) - and not fully in use yet, not even the current CMs have been assigned their titles based on the work (this is ongoing).

The progression goes from associate CM, to CM, to Senior, Staff and lastly Principal (same titles across other jobs) - so a Staff would be the second most senior title career-wise.

Comment: Aw. Am disappointed. Wouldn't say no to whatever CMs y'all can hire 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it doesn't mean necessarily that we *can't* hire a Staff CM, just that we don't plan on posting a job ad requiring someone to be hired at that level.

Comment: Staff is really a unlucky choice in this situation, as really you are all Staff members of SE.

Comment: Well - staff might be in the sense of *has* a staff (people, not stick). The experience level indicated is *roughly* in line with what a CM manager has based off Rosie's hiring, and I'd guess they need one per team and that means one more at least.